# AltBeaconLibrary in service and seperate process. Part 2

Tags: android, xamarin, altbeacon

Help is needed. Thanks to David for the last answer to the question -[AltBeacon service in separate android process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48112010/altbeacon-service-in-separate-android-process/48118497#48118497).
I'm trying to implement on the Xamarin Android - AltBeacon Library in the service and in a separate process. (A separate process is needed to ensure that scanning works constantly, round the clock.
What would the android not cut the scanning after a certain time, after the phone goes into sleep mode).
1. What did I do after David's instructions -
-added attributes in the service definition:
 
    [Service (Name = SERVICE_NAME, Process = ": myProcess", Enabled = true, Exported = false, IsolatedProcess = false)]

- installed a new version of the library - AltBeacon 2.11. To date, Xamarin does not have version 2.11. The latest version is 2.7
   I downloaded the AltBeacon v2.11 native library and wrapped it with Managed Callable Wrappers (MCW). [(https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/)][1].
   As a result, I got a full library on Xamarin.
   - Connected this library to the project. For testing, I removed the Process: myProcess attribute and ran the application.
    In one process, everything works well. The service works and finds the bicons. Perfectly!
    But - 
   As soon as I started the service in another process I stopped getting the bicons.
   After the other method that triggers this is OnBeaconServiceConnect ().

  public void OnBeaconServiceConnect()

  ```
  {
              for (int i = 0; i < guids.Length; i++)
              {
                  var uuid = Identifier.Parse(guids[i]);
                  var region = new Region("R" + i, uuid, null, null);
                  beaconManager.StartRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
              }
      }
  ```

It turns out that the method does not work in the Range Notifier object =(

A rough example of the implementation of the service:

```
  public class myService:Service
 {

 private BeaconWorker beaconWorker;

 public myService()
 {
    beaconWorker=new beaconWorker(DroidApplication.CurrentInstanceApp);
 }

 public void MainMethod()
 {
 var notification = ...Build();
  StartForeground(s_id, notification);

    while(true)
    {
     StartMainWork(guids)              
    }    
 }

 public void StartMainWork(string guid)
 {
    beaconWorker.GetResult();
 }

 }
 /////////////////////////////////////
 public class BeaconWorker:IBeaconConsumer
 {
 List<Beacon> Beacons;
 private Context context;
 private RangeNotifier rangeNotifier;
 private BeaconManager beaconManager;

 //This is main configuring scanning
 public BeaconWorker(Context context)
 {
      Context = context;
          this.guids = ...;
            rangeNotifier = new RangeNotifier();
             BeaconManager.SetDebug(true);
             beaconManager = 
           BeaconManager.GetInstanceForApplication(context);
          beaconManager.SetForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(1000);
         beaconManager.SetForegroundScanPeriod(1000);
        beaconManager.SetBackgroundMode(false);
         var beaconParser = new BeaconParser();
          beaconParser.SetBeaconLayout("...");
           beaconManager.BeaconParsers.Add(beaconParser);
            beaconManager.SetRangeNotifier(rangeNotifier);
            beaconManager.ApplySettings();    
 }

 //Method that do bind
public void GetResult()
{
beaconManager.Bind(this);
Task.Wait(3000);
beaconManager.UnBind(this);
}


 //Implement IBeaconConsumer BindService
  public bool BindService(Intent p0, IServiceConnection p1, int p2)
   {   
      return context.BindService(p0, p1, Bind.AutoCreate);         
   }

  public void OnBeaconServiceConnect()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < guids.Length; i++)
         {
         var uuid = Identifier.Parse(guids[i]);
          var region = new Region("R" + i, uuid, null, null);
            beaconManager.StartRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
         }
     }  


 private class RangeNotifier
 {

 //THIS METHOD DOES NOT INVOKE =(
  public void DidRangeBeaconsInRegion(ICollection<Beacon> beacons, Region region)
            {               
               this.Beacons = beacons;
            }
 }
 }
```

In the logs of the phone there is such information:

```
 Time   Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
01-18 18:52:25.370  AGM A8  Warning 17056   BeaconManager   Ranging/Monitoring may not be controlled from a separate BeaconScanner process.  To remove this warning, please wrap this call in: if (beaconManager.isMainProcess())
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
01-18 18:52:25.370  AGM A8  Debug   17056   BeaconManager   we have a connection to the service now
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
01-18 18:52:25.361  AGM A8  Debug   17056   BeaconManager   consumer count is now: 1
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
01-18 18:52:25.363  AGM A8  Info    17024   BeaconService   beaconService version 2.11 is starting up on the main process
```

I know about the verification David pointed out in the answer to IsMainProcess() method. But how can I call this check if all this happens in the service itself and not in the main application process?
  Tell me where I'm wrong. What else can I add?
  In the article https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/pull/479
  on how much I realized that it makes no sense to specify a RangeNotifier in a separate process. Is it so?
  I will be grateful for any help! Thank you!

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html

Comment: Thank you. I read the article. But I don't understand how it help's me? I using Android 7 and using service in foreground mode(service starts with notification and startForeground() method).

Comment: You have originally put in your question `A separate process is needed to ensure that scanning works constantly, round the clock. What would the android not cut the scanning after a certain time, after the phone goes into sleep mode`. This however is not going to be possible with new background execution limitations and you should plan ahead for this case. You may also want to read about [What is a Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#WhatIsAService) and [Service Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle).

Comment: The best way to approach this would be to make your `Service` "Sticky": https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

Comment: I read the article and understand the consequences. But at the moment I have a task to implement AltBeacon to Android Nougat. I realize that I will need to re-do the service in the future, so that it would work with the new version of the operating system. But it will be in the future. For me, now it is important to do so that AltBeacon worked on Android 7. I am familiar with the life cycle of the service in Android.

Comment: I know the StartService-OnStartCommand -StopService and BindService-UnbindService bindings. I know that OnStartCommand returns constants,
 which indicate how to manage the service after it is closed by the system in case of a lack of resources. I have a very active service. It is multi-threaded and besides AltBeacon it uses gps and send data over the network. I managed to make it unburnt but only when I created a separate process for it. It works constantly. And not cut by the system.

Comment: The question is how to make AltBeacon work in a separate process.
Different timers and alarm managers are not an option. They do not work.

Comment: Only such a scheme works:
  1. BindService + StartForeground
  2. Add Wakelock (after that the service seems to start working constantly BUT after an average of 6-7 hours of work, it stops working,
  as far as I understand it turns on the 4th stage of Doze mode and the service stops working). Without wakelock, gps and the network almost instantly stop working, which is critical for the application.
  3. After the service was rewritten for work in a separate process, the service began to work constantly. GPS and the network began to function. But, AltBeacon stopped working
 Any more ideas?

Comment: I can not find a solution. Probably will not work.